# Debian: How can I easily choose mirrorlist as I did when I install the system?

Tags: debian

When I install the system, in the step of internet configuration, the installer asked me to choose the best mirror I feel. It is very convenient, since I don't need to modify `/etc/apt/source.list` and wonder around the internet to find the source list I need to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your `sources.list` then it'll show something something similar to

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main non-free contrib

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main non-free contrib
```

The "fun" part is that it says `us.debian`; this means "pick a US based server".

Debian maintain a list of regional mirrors for many countries at

```
https://www.debian.org/mirror/list
```

You can pick a regional mirror, or delve down to a specific provider based on that list.

Comment: mine is not looks as 'ftp...', it looks like this: `deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
`

Comment: However I can copy yours, and modify mine...

Comment: @buzhidao Mirrors support multiple protocols. You just selected `http` during installation.

Comment: @PaulNordin yeah, I should selected ftp instead.

Comment: Can I delete this `deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main non-free contrib
`, since I think this is not my local region... It seems that it come from the official sites.

Comment: The "security" entries should be kept, unless you have specific values that replace them.  My entries, above, refer directly to "security.debian.org".

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to do it manually (e.g., in synaptic or edit sources.list and change to one of the mirrors found at https://www.debian.org/mirror/mirrors_full), as far as I know, you will need to install another program. `netselect-apt` can allegedly select the faster/closest mirrors and automatically update your sources.list.

Answer (score 2):

You shoud use `httpredir.debian.org` adress :

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

If you are using `non-free` , you should add the following lines:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

Why you should use [`httpredir.debian.org`](http://httpredir.debian.org/) mirrors?

> The redirector aims to solve the problem of choosing a Debian mirror. It uses the geographic and network location of the user and the mirrors, the architecture of the requested files, IP address family, the availability and freshness of the mirrors, and a few other things.
>
> The result: it selects the best mirror that can serve the file. Give the [**demonstration**](http://httpredir.debian.org/demo.html) a try!

Comment: This is so intelligent. Debian is so smart. ps: is there any risks of using non-free? I mean, is it official and without malwares?

Comment: The `non-free` package` is safe , official and maintained by Debian.